# Ctrl+backtick not working in Linux based terminals

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcut `` Ctrl+` `` (**Ctrl+backtick**) doesn't work in Linux based terminals like `urxvt`, `gnome-terminal`, `xfce-terminal`, Git Bash on Windows, etc.

Is this a bug or a feature?

All other applications like Emacs and VS Code accept this keybinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following keybinding works for my xterm/ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrdb -merge << 'EOF'
XTerm*VT100.translations: #override\n\
Ctrl <Key>`       : string("ls -la")string(0x0d)
EOF
# then start a new xterm
```

With some adaptation, it should work for urxvt and xfce-terminal.

*Update*

For xfce4-terminal, you can put following line in ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/paste" "<Primary>grave")
```

So that Ctrl-` will paste.

Comment: This works only in xterm.

Comment: I know, but you can try to adapt it for urxvt and xfce-terminal. How do you start xfce-terminal ?

Comment: From the applications menu in xfce.